# bash how to remove "__bp_precmd_invoke_cmd" error?

Tags: bash, .bash-profile

I get after each command the error `bash: __bp_precmd_invoke_cmd: command not found` even after the command is successfully executed.

e.g. if I run the `ls` command I get the proper listing of the directory BUT after the listing, I get the following error message

```
bash: __bp_precmd_invoke_cmd: command not found
bash: __bp_interactive_mode: command not found
```

Same about all other commands, **the commands run perfectly well**, but I always get the errors mentioned above after each of the commands.

How to get rid of it?
I tried google but could not solve it.

Answer (score 13):

Using an editor such as nano or vim,
Add the line

```
unset PROMPT_COMMAND
```

to your `.bashrc` file, and it will take effect on the next session.

To apply the change immediately for the life of the current shell session, type

```
unset PROMPT_COMMAND
```

in your terminal window.