# unset PROMPT_COMMAND with screen

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

Recently, for seemingly no reason, I've been getting the same issue as this thread:

[bash how to remove "__bp_precmd_invoke_cmd" error?](https://superuser.com/questions/1007647/bash-how-to-remove-bp-precmd-invoke-cmd-error)

However it only happens when I enter a `screen` session. Issuing `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` at the cli makes the problem go away for that screen session without any issue.

I added this then to my `.screenrc`, however the issue persists. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

From: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html

Add `unsetenv PROMPT_COMMAND` . to your .screenrc file.

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely from https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec which is included in the shell integration for the MacOS terminal emulator https://www.iterm2.com/ . The above solution works of unsetting PROMPT_COMMAND works; a better solution is to identify which shell script is causing the problem. If it is iTerm2, simply stop `.bash{,_profile}` sourcing the iterm integration.

Maybe an iTerm2 shell integration bug? It should check better whether iterm2 is the parent terminal, or give up if it is a terminal multiplexer such as tmux or screen. Personally, I found the iterm2 integration added complexity and confusion like this, and didn't make my life easier.

You may wish to only source the iterm2 integration if not in a multiplexer, and when iterm2 is not a parent terminal. Left as exercise for reader, or iTerm2 developers.

Comment: Ah this could be it, I am indeed using iTerm2. I have been using it (and shell integration) for longer than I think this error has been occurring but perhaps it's a recent update that's done it. I'll experiment and report back!

Comment: Am using iTerm2 + shell integration. Normally works fine, unless I invoke `bash` from the command line, or from emacs via `term "/usr/bin/bash"`, and then I get these errors. If I then `source ~/.bash_profile` (which in turn sources `.bashrc`), everything returns to normal.